# Categories with sub PHP / MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have some troubles with subcategories in my code.

My expectation:

> - Bakery
>
>   - Canned food
>   - Dairy Products
>   - Meat
>
>     - subcategory
>     - subcategory
>     - ...
>     - subcategory
>   - Sweets and Snacks
>
>     - subcategory
>     - subcategory
>     - ...
>     - subcategory

MYSQL Table schema:

Categories:

id
category
name
url
type

```
$res = mysql_query("SELECT `id`, `name`, `url` FROM `categories` WHERE `type`='category' ORDER BY `name` ASC") or die(mysql_error());
while ($arr = mysql_fetch_array($res))
{
    $faq_categ[$arr['id']]['title'] = $arr['name'];
    $faq_categ[$arr['id']]['url'] = $arr['url'];
}
$res = mysql_query("SELECT `id`, `name`, `category`, `url` FROM `categories` WHERE `type`='subcategory' ORDER BY `name` ASC") or die(mysql_error());
while ($arr = mysql_fetch_array($res)) 
{
    $faq_categ[$arr['category']]['items'][$arr['id']]['name'] = $arr['name'];
    $faq_categ[$arr['category']]['items'][$arr['id']]['url'] = $arr['url'];
}
if (isset($faq_categ)) 
{
    foreach ($faq_categ as $id => $temp) 
    {
        $textbuilder .= '<li><a href="/products/'.$faq_categ[$id]['url'].'/all" title="">'.$faq_categ[$id]['title'].'</a>';
        if (array_key_exists("items", $faq_categ[$id])) 
        {
            foreach ($faq_categ[$id]['items'] as $id2 => $temp)
            {
                $textbuilder .= '<small><a href="/products/'.$faq_categ[$id]['url'].'/'.$faq_categ[$id]['items'][$id2]['url'].'" title="">٠'.$faq_categ[$id]['items'][$id2]['name'].'</a></small>';
            }
        }
        $textbuilder .= '</li>';
    }
}
```

The result: http://www.picupload.us/images/454result.png

Thanks for your time,
Fox Sank

EDIT:

Here is the table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `categories` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `category` int(10) default NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `url` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `type` varchar(255) default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=17 ;

INSERT INTO `categories` (`id`, `category`, `name`, `url`, `type`) VALUES
(1, 1, 'Bakery', 'brakery', 'category'),
(2, 2, 'Dairy Products', 'dairy-products', 'category'),
(3, 3, 'Sweets and Snacks', 'sweets-and-snacks', 'category'),
(4, 3, 'Corn puffs', 'corn-puffs', 'subcategory'),
(5, 3, 'Biscuits', 'biscuits', 'subcategory'),
(6, 3, 'Cakes', 'cakes', 'subcategory'),
(7, 3, 'Pretzels', 'pretzels', 'subcategory'),
(8, 4, 'Canned food', 'canned-food', 'category'),
(9, 5, 'Meat', 'meat', 'category'),
(10, 5, 'Salami', 'salami', 'subcategory'),
(11, 5, 'Sausages', 'sausages', 'subcategory'),
(12, 5, 'Ham', 'ham', 'subcategory'),
(13, 5, 'Delicatessen', 'delicatessen', 'subcategory'),
(14, 5, 'Frankfurters', 'frankfurters', 'subcategory'),
(15, 5, 'Polony', 'polony', 'subcategory'),
(16, 5, 'Smoked', 'smoked', 'subcategory'),
(17, 5, 'Pate', 'pate', 'subcategory');
```

Comment: Could you add a dump of your categories table data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I try this code, its works..
you will try this...

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `categorylist` (
 `id` int(5) NOT NULL auto_increment,
`cname` varchar(25) collate utf8_unicode_ci default NULL,
`pid` int(5) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
KEY `pid` (`pid`)
) ;



INSERT INTO `categorylist` (`id`, `cname`, `pid`) VALUES
(1, 'Entertainment', 0),
(2, 'movies', 1),
(3, 'actor', 2),
(4, 'actress', 2),
(5, 'Drama', 1),
(7, 'sports', 0),
(8, 'comedian', 2),
(9, 'political', 0);



<?php
include "header.php";
 include "dbconn.php";

 $qry="SELECT * FROM categorylist";
 $result=mysql_query($qry);


 $arrayCategories = array();

 while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){ 
    $arrayCategories[$row['id']] = array("pid" => $row['pid'], "name" =>  $row['cname']);   
  }
//createTree($arrayCategories, 0);

 function createTree($array, $currentParent, $currLevel = 0, $prevLevel = -1) {

foreach ($array as $categoryId => $category) {

    if ($currentParent == $category['pid']) {                       

        if ($currLevel > $prevLevel) echo " <ul> "; 

        if ($currLevel == $prevLevel) echo " </li> ";

        echo '<li id="'.$categoryId.'" onclick=child(this.id);><span>'.$category['name'].'</span>';

        if ($currLevel > $prevLevel) { $prevLevel = $currLevel; }

        $currLevel++; 

        createTree ($array, $categoryId, $currLevel, $prevLevel);

        $currLevel--;               
    }   

}

if ($currLevel == $prevLevel) echo " </li>  </ul> ";

}   
?>
<div id="content" class="general-style1">
<?php
 if(mysql_num_rows($result)!=0)
 {
?>
<ul>
    <li id="0" class="root"><span>Categories</span>
    <?php createTree($arrayCategories, 0); ?>
</li>
</ul>
<?php
}
?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your data is wrong:

```
(9, 5, 'Meat', 'meat', 'category'),
```

Should be:

```
(9, 9, 'Meat', 'meat', 'category'),
```

And

```
(10, 5, 'Salami', 'salami', 'subcategory'),
(11, 5, 'Sausages', 'sausages', 'subcategory'),
(12, 5, 'Ham', 'ham', 'subcategory'),
(13, 5, 'Delicatessen', 'delicatessen', 'subcategory'),
(14, 5, 'Frankfurters', 'frankfurters', 'subcategory'),
(15, 5, 'Polony', 'polony', 'subcategory'),
(16, 5, 'Smoked', 'smoked', 'subcategory'),
(17, 5, 'Pate', 'pate', 'subcategory');
```

Should be:

```
(10, 9, 'Salami', 'salami', 'subcategory'),
(11, 9, 'Sausages', 'sausages', 'subcategory'),
(12, 9, 'Ham', 'ham', 'subcategory'),
(13, 9, 'Delicatessen', 'delicatessen', 'subcategory'),
(14, 9, 'Frankfurters', 'frankfurters', 'subcategory'),
(15, 9, 'Polony', 'polony', 'subcategory'),
(16, 9, 'Smoked', 'smoked', 'subcategory'),
(17, 9, 'Pate', 'pate', 'subcategory');
```