# PHP: Dynamically Nested Unordered Lists

Tags: php, html-lists, performance

I am currently echoing an array coming from a query and I need to present them in nested unordered lists. I am trying to find a way to do this procedure infinitely because I am currently manually echoing each nested ul's (if they have one) only up to the depth that I manually code. Please help me if there is a way to automatically echo the ul's up to depth "n".

This is my current logic only echoing up to depth 5:

```
<ul class="parent_tree"><?php
  foreach($category_tree as $category_level_1)
  {
    echo '<li><a href="#">' . $category_level_1['name'] . '</a>';

    if(array_key_exists('children', $category_level_1))
    {
      echo '<ul>';

      foreach($category_level_1['children'] as $category_level_2)
      {
        echo '<li><a href="#">' . $category_level_2['name'] . '</a>';

        if(array_key_exists('children', $category_level_2))
        {
          echo '<ul>';

          foreach($category_level_2['children'] as $category_level_3)
          {
            echo '<li><a href="#">' . $category_level_3['name'] . '</a>';

            if(array_key_exists('children', $category_level_3))
            {
              echo '<ul>';

              foreach($category_level_3['children'] as $category_level_4)
              {
                echo '<li><a href="#">' . $category_level_4['name'] . '</a>';

                if(array_key_exists('children', $category_level_4))
                {
                  echo '<ul>';

                  foreach($category_level_4['children'] as $category_level_5)
                  {
                    echo '<li><a href="#">' . $category_level_5['name'] . '</a>';

                    //level 6 goes here

                    echo '</li>';
                  }

                  echo '</ul>';
                }

                echo '</li>';
              }

              echo '</ul>';
            }

            echo '</li>';
          }

          echo '</ul>';
        }

        echo '</li>';
      }

      echo '</ul>';
    }

    echo '</li>';
  }
?>
</ul>
```

Comment: Have you heard of recursion?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Echo menu tree with recursive function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10782810/echo-menu-tree-with-recursive-function)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haven't tested it, but you'd want to use recursion for this. Basically you continue to call the same function with different parameters. It'll loop through everything and exit when there are no more children arrays.

```
function recursive_list($category) {
    echo '<ul>';
    foreach($category as $item){
        echo '<li><a href="#">' . $item['name'] . '</a>';
        if(array_key_exists('children', $item)) {
            recursive_list($item);
        }
    }
}
```