# Trying to generate tree's HTML out of 2 dimensional array

Tags: php, html, loops, recursion

I am trying to generate the HTML for tree like (jsTree) out of a 2d array with no success.

I have the following array: [My Array](https://gist.github.com/yanivkalfa/5708038)

and from this array i would like to create a tree html (ul and li) structure like:

```
<ul id="ParentId-0">
    <li id="categoryID-1" data-parentid="1">
        bla bla
        <ul id="ParentId-1">
            <li id="categoryID-20" data-parentid="20">
                some Title
                <ul id="ParentId-20">......</ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>

    <li id="categoryID-2" data-parentid="2">
        second li Title
        <ul id="ParentId-2">
            <li id="categoryID-46" data-parentid="46">
                Another Title
                <ul id="ParentId-46">
                    <li id="categoryID-300" data-parentid="30">
                        And another Category
                        <ul id="ParentId-300"></ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Anyone with an idea?

**Edit**

I've tried using DOMDocument to create the tree and it worked however it took like 40 - 50  seconds to load and i am trying to find a faster way.

Comment: I'd recommend you start by looking for the root element (the one without a parent) and, recusivly, append to it all the elements that are its children. For exemple, you could have a function that takes an identifier as input, and that returns an array containing the elements that have this identifier as parent, recursivly. Once you have your tree as pure information, turn it into html (recursivly again)

Comment: Lol robert :-) yea ^^

Comment: [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10782810/echo-menu-tree-with-recursive-function) is a sample ;)

Comment: Ended up using DOMdocument works fast and correctly, but thanks alot for this link i will try it as well maybe its like a second faster