# PHP parent child submenu

Tags: php, mysql, submenu

I am interesting how can I do submenu with parent-child  values in PHP.

My MySQL base is:

```
id | menu_id | menu | url | title | parent_id
---|---------|------|-----|------|------------
1  |1        |admin |index|home  | 0
2  |2        |admin |page |page  | 1

Etc.
```

From the base to collect the data by:

```
SELECT * FROM admin WHERE `menu` = "admin" ORDER BY menu_id ASC
```

and

```
SELECT * FROM admin WHERE `parent_id` = "id" ORDER BY menu_id ASC
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by parent-child menu? are you talking about css dropdown menus? or about php arrays with keys and values?

Comment: It's called recursion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10782810/echo-menu-tree-with-recursive-function

Comment: Use order by parent_id ASC