# Array Formatting in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to create nested menu via mysql and php.

When I'm creating multidimensional array from this:

```
$ref = [];
$items = [];
foreach($row as $row) {
    $thisRef =& $ref[$row->id];
    $thisRef['parent_id'] = $row->parent_id;
    $thisRef['menu_id'] = $row->menu_id;
    $thisRef['type'] = $row->type;
    $thisRef['id'] = $row->id;
    if($row->parent_id == 0) {
        $items[] =& $thisRef;
    } else {
        $ref[$row->parent_id]['sub'][] =& $thisRef;
    }
}
```

it generates array like this.

```
Array(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [parent_id] => 0
            [menu_id] => 10
            [type] => p
            [id] => 93
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [sub] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [parent_id] => 88
                            [menu_id] => 10
                            [type] => b
                            [id] => 92
                            [sub] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            parent_id] => 92
                                            [menu_id] => 8
                                            [type] => c
                                            [id] => 94
                                        )
                                )
                        )
                     [1] => Array
                        (
                            [parent_id] => 88
                            [menu_id] => 8
                            [type] => c
                            [id] => 90
                        )

                )

            [parent_id] => 0
            [menu_id] => 5
            [type] => p
            [id] => 88
        )
    )
)
```

and it's good but I'd like to change name of second array key sub I mean if array all ready has sub, second sub would be subofsub, I tried to check it with isset and array_key_exists but it just messes my array.

Comment: Some sensible code indentation would be a good idea. 
It helps us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**.
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/) for your own benefit. 
You may be asked to amend this code in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly not really following the question and a little confused with the by refs.

Are you simply trying to do something like this?

```
<?php

$ref   = [];
$items = [];
$subCount = 0;

foreach ($row as $row) {
    $thisRef = &$ref[$row->id];
    $thisRef['parent_id'] = $row->parent_id;
    $thisRef['menu_id'] = $row->menu_id;
    $thisRef['type'] = $row->type;
    $thisRef['id'] = $row->id;
    if($row->parent_id == 0) {
        $items[] = &$thisRef;
    } else {
        $subCount++;
        $ref[$row->parent_id]['sub-' . $subCount][] = &$thisRef;
    }
}
```

Comment: its similar to what i want but its not, i want to check somehow if array all ready has sub and put in that sub renamed sub

something like this.
array[1]->[sub]->[0]->[subofsub]

Comment: If we expressed that as an integer value we could call it 'depth' yes? Are you familiar with the concept of recursion? Not sure I want to try and explain using your existing code. Might be worth reading up some on the topic? Posts like: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10782810/echo-menu-tree-with-recursive-function