# Combine two arrays with each other and get names from MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, database-design, variables

**Problem:**

To combine two arrays with each other and build an array using data from a MySQL table. In one table (**betyg_answers**) I have two columns called Categories and Items.

- **Categories** contain: 1,5,9,13,16
- **Items** contain: 2,3,4,6,7,8,10,11,12,14,15,17,18

These values are stored in variables: $categories and $items.

In the other table (**betyg_category**) I store the names of each category and name as following:

[image]

**Question:**

How would I do to build one big array that starts with Categories on the super level and go down to Items on the lower level?

In other words I would like the array to look like:

```
Litteratur (Category = 1)
    Integration av källorna (Item = 2)
    Belysning av egna resultat (Item = 3)
    Referenser (Item = 4)
Validitet (Category = 2)
    Huvudsyfte (Item = 5)
    Oberoende och beroende variabler (Item = 6)
    Analysmetoderna (Item = 7)

    and so forth..
```

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: you see this link..
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10215980/categories-with-sub-php-mysql/10244518#10244518

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming and hopefully you're using PDO:

```
$sql = '
    SELECT
        a.CID,
        a.Item,
        a.Parent,
        IF(NOT a.Parent, (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CID) FROM betyg_category WHERE Parent = a.CID), NULL) AS catitems
    FROM
        betyg_category a
    ORDER BY
        a.CID';
$stmt = $pdo->query($sql);
$resultset = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_GROUP|PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$itemarray = array();

foreach($resultset as $row)
{
    if(!empty($row[0]['catitems']))
    {
        foreach(explode(',', $row[0]['catitems']) as $cid)
        {
            $itemarray[$row[0]['Item']][$cid] = $resultset[$cid][0]['Item'];
        }
    }
    elseif(!$row[0]['Parent']) // Account for categories with no items in it
    {
        $itemarray[$row[0]['Item']] = array();
    }
}
```

You can then visualize the array with:

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($itemarray);
echo '</pre>';
```

Which gives you:

```
Array
(
    [Litteratur] => Array
        (
            [2] => Integration av källorna
            [3] => Belysning av egna resultat
            [4] => Referenser
        )

    [Validitet] => Array
        (
            [6] => Huvudsyfte
            [7] => Oberoende och beroende variabler
            [8] => Analysmetoderna
        )

    [Reliabilitet] => Array
        (
            [10] => Metodval
            [11] => Metodbeskrivning
            [12] => Databearbetning
        )

    [Språk, stil och struktur] => Array
        (
            [14] => Språk och stil
            [15] => Struktur
        )

    [Arbetssätt] => Array
        (
            [17] => Försvar och opposition
            [18] => Etiska och samhälleliga aspekter
        )

    [Etik] => Array
        (
            [20] => Test 1
        )

)
```

Comment: I am using PDO but with your code I get a blank page, without it the content returns. I basically did a copy/paste considering you got all column names correctly as well as the table name. On top, I checked the database connection and it works. What could be wrong? I'm using MySQL.

Comment: My example code isn't supposed to output anything to the page. It just builds an array which you can visualize using the code I gave in the second codebox. When you print_r the `$itemarray`, what does it give you?

Comment: It gives me a blank page. It's very strange considering that the db connection is OK and all columns and table names are correctly spelled.

Comment: Weird, it should at least give you something like `Array()`, but just a blank page? Do you have `error_reporting(E_STRICT|E_ALL);` so that you are given all errors?

Comment: No error at all, I'm using PHP Version 5.2.17. You can find the database table here: http://pastebin.com/zU2map4x if you like to try it.

Comment: How come you are setting `$pdo = null` after creating it? That nullifies the PDO object. Also, make sure you specify the dbname in the DSN. It works fine for me, see the output I got in my latest edit.

Comment: Excellent, it works. One final question: how would I get the CID instead of the name? Now it's Litteratur, Validitet, etc. but I would like it to be 1, 5, etc.

Comment: Just replace all instances of `$itemarray[$row[0]['Item']]` with `$itemarray[$row[0]['CID']]`

Comment: Thank you for the advice, but now I'm not getting anything at all.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12574/discussion-between-zane-bien-and-kexxcream)

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = mysql_query("select * from betyg_category where CID IN($categories)");
$array = array();
while($mainrow = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
$array[] = $mainrow['Item'] . "(Category = " .$mainrow['CID']. ")";
$child = mysql_query("select * from betyg_category where Parent = " .$mainrow['CID'] . "");
while($childrow = mysql_fetch_array($child)) {
$array[] = $childrow['Item'] . "(Item = " .$childrow['CID']. ")";
}
}
```