# What's the best way to store a path/hierarchy structure in MySQL database?

Tags: php, mysql, database, structure, hierarchy

I have an archive of articles, each belonging to various categories and subcategories. What is the best way to structure and store this in a database?

Comment: see this.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10215980/categories-with-sub-php-mysql/10244518#10244518

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See Bill Karwin's slide show on various ways to store heirarchical data in a MySQL database.

- [Models for heirarchical data](http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/models-for-hierarchical-data)

The four methods he covers are:

- Adjacency List
- Path Enumeration
- Nested Sets
- Closure Table

The different methods make it easier or harder to perform certain common operations such as making updates to the data or finding an entire subtree. Take a look at slide 69 that compares the different approaches.