# Treeview populated from database

Tags: php, mysql, database, treeview

I have been trying to figure out how to create a treeview which is populated from a database using various examples I have come across but have not been successful so far.

My database is structured like:

`id |  parent_id  |  title  |  Urgency` (Urgency is not implemented yet)

The end result should generate a treeview where the value of urgency dictates the image used for each item.

The code I have been trying to utilise lately is:

```
<hmtl>
<body>
<?php

function get_children($parent, $level = 1)
{
$result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM treeview_items WHERE parent_id = '.$parent);
$result2 = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC);
#for avoiding some errors
if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0)
    #start the list
    echo '<ul>';
    foreach($result2 as $row) {
        #print the item, you can also make links out of these
        echo '<li>'.$row['title'].'</li>';
        #this is similar to our last code
        #this function calls it self, so its recursive
        get_children($row['id'], $level+1);
    }
    #close the list
echo '</ul>';
}

mysql_connect('localhost', 'root');
mysql_select_db('test');

$result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM treeview_items');
$result2 = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC);

#for avoiding some errors
if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
#start the list
echo '<ul>';
foreach($result2 as $row) {
    #print the item, you can also make links out of these
    echo '<li>'.$row['title'].'</li>';
    #recursive function(made in next step) for getting all the subs by passing   
 id of main item
    get_children($row['id']);
}
#end the list
echo '</ul>';
#some message if the database is empty
}
else echo 'No Items';

#clear the memory
mysql_free_result($result);
?>
</body>
<html>
```

Basically the code I have doesn't work. What can I try to fix it?

### Edit

I altered some of the code to fix a couple of errors
So now what I see is:

- 1
- 2
- 5

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\Program Files\EasyPHP-5.3.9\www\test.php on line 13

repeated 100 times until it aborts. Not sure why, because both `foreach()` in the code are the same, but the one inside the function doesn't work.

Comment: `#this function calls it self, so its recursive` :)

Comment: Before you do the foreach (that's failing), could you do `print_r($result2); exit();` - that'll show us what's actually in the array and kill the script after that point (easier for debugging at that point)

Comment: Array ( [id] => 2 [parent_id] => 1 [title] => sub header 1 )

is displayed when I input your code just above the foreach()

Comment: See this ... its help to you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10215980/categories-with-sub-php-mysql/10244518#10244518

Comment: @jey Thanks, you should post it as an answer so i can accept it! :)

Comment: That is already accepted.. just you give only vote for that answer..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for all the help but Jey managed to solve my problem by basically giving me entirely new code lol

Here is the link to his code on another question:
[Categories with sub PHP / MYSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10215980/categories-with-sub-php-mysql/10244518#10244518)

Thank you Jey, and everyone else! :)

Answer (score 0):

The reason the function call is failing is because you have not wrapped that code in PHP tags, but instead you've wrapped them in JS tags.

Answer (score 0):

replace the `<script...` line with `<?php` and the `</script>` line with `?>`

you have server side code in php, not client side javascript (judging by the syntax)